# Failed spring boot app with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.of

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, build, jar

facing NoSuchMethodError, when I run my spring boot(v2.7.2) build jar file on my cmd. It's works fine on Eclipse IDE

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        try {
            Role role1 = new Role();
            role1.setId(AppConstants.ADMIN_USER);
            role1.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    
            Role role2 = new Role();
            role2.setId(AppConstants.NORMAL_USER);
            role2.setName("ROLE_NORMAL");       
    
            List<Role> roles = List.of(role1, role2); //@line 50
    
            List<Role> result = this.roleRepo.saveAll(roles);
    
            result.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.getName()));
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are running your code against an incompatible java version

Comment: The method which is metioned in the stacktrace was introduced in java 9

Comment: BTW: Please add the stacktrace as text not as image

Comment: And according to the stacktrace you are running your application with Java 1.8

Comment: Thanks @Jens, it is java version incompatible issue